# How to change a picture with a timer

Tags: c#, wpf, image, timer

I'm trying to change a picture with a 2 seconds time laps. It should be only once and not an unanding time laps.

I googled all kinds of altenitives but I couldn't find it. Like thread.sleep(2000) doesn't work because it freezes the interface.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

public void RemoveImage()
    {
        Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("path to image 2"));
        SetTimer();            
    }

private void SetTimer()
    {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

private void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("path to image 3"));
    }
```

XAML code

```
<Window

<Image Source="path to image 1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="8" 
Name="Image" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalAlignment="Center"></Image>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

With this code I get to the second picture but as it is getting to the last picture you get an error System.InvalidOperationException for image 3. Hope you could help me with any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer does not work on UI thread, so you can't change the controls in your `OnTimedEvent` without calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `Dispatcher.Invoke` with a `System.Timers.Timer`.

Instead, use a `DispatcherTimer`, which already calls its Tick handler in the UI thread.:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;

private void SetTimer()
{
    timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2) };
    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("path to image 3"));
    timer.Stop();
}
```

Comment: What I wrote above is a Microsoft's official sample. Saying that Microsoft's official sample is something that should not be done, then going as far as downvoting, requesting deleting of answer etc is silly. I accept that your answer is a very good one but my answer is absolutely correct too and it was accepted because it works.

Comment: @IvanIčin That is not an "official sample" of how to use a timer in WPF. Why do you think there is the DispatcherTimer class? Any other approach is just nonsense. And an answer that recommends using Dispatcher.Invoke in some timer other than DispatcherTimer is just a bad advice, hence the downvote

Comment: That is the official sample on how to use Dispatcher.Invoke and it uses Timer. You obviously don't like it and it is fine to have your own preferences but you should respect some conventions made by people that actually made the framework.

Comment: It's not about preferences, but about simplicity. The fact that Microsoft shows a Timer.Elapsed handler in a piece of sample code in the Dispatcher.Invoke documentation doesn't mean that that is the right way to use a timer in WPF. You would of course use Dispatcher.Invoke if you are expanding legacy code that already has a System.Timers.Timer, but of course not when you write new code.

Comment: It is about ego. The fact that Microsoft shows Timer.Elapsed means that it is acceptable solution. It is just your ego whether your going to say that or not, logic is more than obvious.

Comment: @IvanIčin Sorry, but that's plain wrong. The only reasonable answer to the question "how to use a timer that ticks in a WPF app's UI thread" is: "Use a DispatcherTimer. That's what it was made for".